# Configure NVidia GT440 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nvidia

I would like to know how to get a better configuration for my NVidia graphics card because actually I'm playing League of Legends in Linux, and I get about 20fps less than if I was running it in Windows. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Go to dash and type software sources, Open software soruces and click on the additional drivers tab, then select the Nvidia 310 or 313 drivers and activate them - then reboot.

Check out my question - will give you some ideas of the issues that are still their with Unity.

I would recommend that if you want to game , install the Gnome Desktop environment from the software centre - log out and select the Gnome Failback session (no effects) - this will give you a smooth gaming experience.

[Improving Steam performance on Ubuntu 13.04 with Nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301042/ubuntu-13-04-unity-steam-nvidia)