# high vram memory unity/compiz with nvidia

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz, steam

I run my desktop at the high resolution of 1920x1200 and am finding the vram usage is very high; nearly all my graphics memory (~200-220mb used). I'm checking my vram usage with the nvidia xserver settings app.

This wouldn't be an issue except when I run games, such as half life 2, then can suddenly slow to a crawl as the video memory is used up. If I run the games using a different desktop environment, like LXDE, everything runs fun (not as fast as windows, but much better!)

I have an nvidia quadro 570m (same as the geforce fx 8600m I think.)

This is with the ubuntu 13.10 and 12.04 and the default proprietary drivers or the latest (331.20), plus some of the older ones, the result is the same.

Is there some setting I'm missing to free up the memory when another app is opened full screen? Or is this a known bug? It seems a huge amount of vram to use just for the desktop.

My question is similar to this one I think:
[Improving Steam performance on Ubuntu 13.04 with Nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301042/improving-steam-performance-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-nvidia)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I have 1GB VRAM and unity consumes usually around 850MB - this makes most of the games unable to even run and if they do, they are choppy as ***.

Although not a solution, I found a small "workaround" to enable some basic gaming:

Just before running the game/program I jump to text-only terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then immediately jump back to unity with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. This seems to free quite a lot of VRAM and enables the games to run smoothly. Hovewer, I haven't had a gaming session longer than about one hour, so I cannot comment if the performance does not go down over time.

**Edit:** forgot to add - I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and a Cuda-developer drivers 340.